why is AWS saying my ARN is not valid with get-license-usage when it is fine with get-license-configuration
I'm trying to retrieve oracle license usage from license manager.
If I do
aws license-manager get-license-configuration --license-configuration-arn arn:aws:license-manager:eu-west-1:002909278xxx:license-configuration:lic-1cbfffa9d1c64e2ea7dd03a76e81xxxx

I get results.
But If I do
aws license-manager get-license-usage --license-arn arn:aws:license-manager:eu-west-1:002909278xxx:license-configuration:lic-1cbfffa9d1c64e2ea7dd03a76e81xxxx

I get
An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the GetLicenseUsage operation: Invalid license ARN

what am I doing wrong?

aws license-manager get-license-configuration expects license-configuration-arn and that is what you provide, so that works.
aws license-manager get-license-usage expects license-arn and you are providing license-configuration-arn, so that fails.

The error you're encountering is because you are using a license configuration ARN instead of a license ARN for the get-license-usage command
To retrieve the correct license ARN, you need to list the licenses associated with your license configuration. Run the following command:
aws license-manager list-licenses --license-configuration-arn arn:aws:license-manager:eu-west-1:002909278xxx:license-configuration:lic-1cbfffa9d1c64e2ea7dd03a76e81xxxx

Look through the output to find the license ARN that matches the license configuration for Oracle. It will look something like this:
arn:aws:license-manager:eu-west-1:002909278xxx:license:lic-xxxxxxxxxxxx

Now use the below command to get the get-license-usage
aws license-manager get-license-usage --license-arn arn:aws:license-manager:eu-west-1:002909278xxx:license:lic-xxxxxxxxxxxx


thank you but I only have one self-managed license under my arn (I have other objects and each has a different arn). I have tried the aws license-manager list-licenses --license-configuration-arn arn:aws:license-manager:eu-west-1:002909278xxx:license-configuration:lic-1cbfffa9d1c64e2ea7dd03a76e81xxxx but I get Unknown options: --license-configuration-arn, arn:aws:license-manager:eu-west-1:002909278xxx:license-configuration:lic-1cbfffa9d1c64e2ea7dd03a76e81xxxx

just try   aws license-manager list-licenses
This command will list licenses, including their ARNs, if any have been issued. And search whether license is issued or not, it should be in the format :  arn:aws:license-manager:region:account-id:license:license-id    .
If you haven't issued any licenses yet, you need to do so.

yes I had tried that and it returns an empty list. {     "Licenses": [] }

it means you haven't issued any licenses based on the license configuration, you need to do so.

ok how do I do that? cannot see anything about issuing on AWS doc. What is strange is that I can see the licenses in use: `Summary
Status
Active
License type
vCPU
vCPUs in use
40 of 322
` on AWS UI

ok at the end I gave up on get-license-usage. I now use get-license-configuration with --query ConsumedLicenses and it returns me 40 which is the number of consumed licenses

Since this doesn't answer the original question, it would be better as a comment.
